# Adding onclick event on dynamically created HTML caused an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm using ajax to get an results from code behind, when I Get those results I'm creating an a divs. And this works fine, adding a div dynamically.

Now I Want to add on each div onclick event which should raise some method when it's clicked, so here is my full code:

```
<script>
    function onSelectGroup(Id) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "Product/GetProductsByGroupId",
            data: { groupId: Id }
        })
.done(function (response) {

    $(".products").html("");
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
//I wrote onclick = "addProduct(response[i])" to generate for each div each onclick event
        let item = '<div class="col-md-3"> <div class="Product-holder" onclick="addProduct(' + response[i] + ')" id=' + response[i].ProductId + '><img class="img-responsive" src="images/maxresdefault.jpg"><p class="product-title" style="color:white;margin-top:5px;text-align:center;"> ' + response[i].Title + '</p></div></div>';
        //Trying to append it to my .product class because it's parent of this divs above
        $(".products").append(item);

    }})};

    function addProduct(product) {
        console.log(product.Title);
    }
</script>
```

But when I click on any of my generated divs I get an following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I'm looking for issue for 3h allready, and I'm really stucked here..

Any kind of help would be great.
Thanks

P.S

CODE BEHIND - C # METHOD:

```
public ActionResult GetProductsByGroupId(int groupId)
{
            var products = ProductController.GetProductsByGroupId(groupId);
            if(products)
            {
                List<Product> productlist = new List<Product>();
                foreach (var item in products)
                {
                    Product product = new Product();
                    product.ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(item.Id);
                    product.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(item.Price);
                    product.Title = item.Title;
                    productlist.Add(product);
                }

                return Json(productlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `response[i]`

Comment: not sure but can you add `" "` around the line `id=' + response[i].ProductId + '` like this `id="' + response[i].ProductId + '"`

Comment: @brk it's an object that I'm getting from a code behind, it has values: Id,Title,Price

Comment: how come you say its an object i dont see you setting the dataType to json ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam wait a moment I will post a code behind (method GetProductsByGroupId) but I started to receive error after I added onclick ="addProduct(response[i])";

Comment: @billy_56 probaly you cannot pass an object like this way

Comment: @brk probably I can't, well I must find a way to do it properly

Comment: @brk I tried pass anything to a addArticle method but it's not working, but event is triggering, if I write console.log("something"); in my method it's trigger, cause I can see "something" in console..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `onclick` and use [delegate](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_delegate.asp), you are passing an object to a function which convert `response[i]` to text  `[Object object]`, use [data-*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) attributes to hold data for each object and attach an event to the div with the class `product`, on click of the div we'll use `$(this)` to reference the current clicked div and access its `data` attributes.

```js
$(".products").html("");
 var response = [{ProductId:4, Title:"Doe", Price: 34.89}, {ProductId:6, Title:"Jane", Price: 20.99}];
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
//I wrote onclick = "addProduct(response[i])" to generate for each div each onclick event
        let item = '<div class="col-md-3"> <div class="Product-holder product" data-price="'+ response[i].Price +'" data-title="' + response[i].Title + '" id=' + response[i].ProductId + '><img class="img-responsive" src="images/maxresdefault.jpg"><p class="product-title" style="color:white;margin-top:5px;text-align:center;"> ' + response[i].Title + '</p></div></div>';
        //Trying to append it to my .product class because it's parent of this divs above
        $(".products").append(item);
//console.log(item);
    };
    
$(document).on('click', '.product', function(){
  var product = {Title: $(this).data('title'), ProductId: $(this).attr('id'), Price: $(this).data('price')};
  console.log(product);
  // here use ajax to add this product
});
```

```css
body {
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="products"></div>
```

Comment: now explain your aswer very detaiiled and it will be one cool answer ( for example: why you had to use event delegation, why did you use data tags and so on) :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) jquery method!

> **Description**: Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.

So you basically need to bind the onClick event to the parent div, and pass a selector that will appear later on the child divs.

```
<script>
function onSelectGroup(Id) {
    $.ajax(
        //Do your ajax call here
    ).done(function (response) {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        let item = '<div class="event-target"></div>'
        $(".products").append(item);
}})};

// Here's where the magic happens. 
// We bind the event to the elements that have the 'event-target' class
//inside the element that have the 'products' class.

$('.products').on('click', '.event-target', function(){
    console.log(this);
})
</script>
```

**Warning**: take care using delegate, if you use the wrong selector you can end up triggering the event for each element on the page, or even recursivelly (belive me, have made it a lot...)

Answer (score 0):

Use [**data**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attributes to store any data & on click retrieve the data attribute.The code is not tested but hopefully it will work

```
let item = '<div class="col-md-3">' +
    ' <div class="Product-holder" ' +
    'onclick="addProduct(this)"' +
    ' data-title="'+response[i].Title+'"' +
    ' id=' + response[i].ProductId + '>' +
    '<img class="img-responsive" src="images/maxresdefault.jpg">' +
    '<p class="product-title" style="color:white;margin-top:5px;text-align:center;"> ' + response[i].Title + '</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';
$(".products").append(item);

function addProduct(product) {
    console.log($(product).data('title'));
}
```

Also you need to delegate the event since they are dynamically created element

```
$("body").on("click",".Product-holder",function(){
   console.log($(product).data('title'));
})
```

In this case the inline event handler that is `onclick` function will be redundant

Comment: I will try it soon and what about my code, what's the reason it's not working?

Comment: @A.Wolff oh, thanks, and by looking at this code, addProduct method will be fired when object is created? and that's something I don't want to face..

Comment: where did you put your block of code with delegation?

Comment: in same javascript file

Answer (score 0):

Let me going to explant your code.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        let item = '<div class="col-md-3"> <div class="Product-holder" onclick="addProduct(' + response[i] + ')" id=' + response[i].ProductId + '><img class="img-responsive" src="images/maxresdefault.jpg"><p class="product-title" style="color:white;margin-top:5px;text-align:center;"> ' + response[i].Title + '</p></div></div>';
        $(".products").append(item);
    }})};
```

On these line of code, I saw that you have added strings to a variable.
but more exception **response[i].ProductId** seem like **response[i]** was an object. 
but in Javascript you can't add an **object** to **String** by **+** operator, it will be return "*string [object] string*". What is solution for that??

1. Convert your object to JSON String like **{"id": 123, "name": "Product name"}**, that will show in html code like this **onclick='addProduct({"id": 123, "name": "Product name"})'** remember that onclick = **'**  not **"**